# speed issue when running this code

Tags: excel, vba, macos

this is my codes. please i need your help.. thanks in advance

Sub Update()

ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False
    sheet3.Activate

```
Range("A2:AI50").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets(Sheets.Count)
Dim LR As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

With Sheets("Sheet1")
    LR = .Range("AI" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("A1:AI" & LR).Copy ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
End With

With Sheets("Sheet2")
    LR = .Range("AI" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("A2:AI" & LR).Copy ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
```

'----------------------------------------------------

```
ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False
Dim cntrl As Integer
Dim CountList As Integer
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

CountList = Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For Each x In Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:AI" & Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    For cntrl = CountList To 1 Step -1
    If x.Value = Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(cntrl, 1).Value Then
    Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(cntrl, 1).EntireRow.Delete
    Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A2:AI" & Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Interior.ColorIndex = 22
End If

Next cntrl
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
```

'---------------------------------------------------

```
ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False
Dim reyng  As Range
Dim up     As Range
Dim cl     As Range
Dim r1     As Long
Dim R      As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

With sheet2
    Set reyng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
    End With

With sheet3
    Set up = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
    R = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
End With

On Error Resume Next
For Each cl In reyng
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(up, cl.Value) = 0 Then
        R = R + 1
        cl.EntireRow.Copy sheet3.Cells(R, 1)
        sheet3.Cells(R, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 40
        sheet3.Cells(R, 2).Interior.ColorIndex = 40
        sheet3.Cells(R, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = 40
        sheet3.Cells(R, 4).Interior.ColorIndex = 40
        sheet3.Cells(R, 5).Interior.ColorIndex = 40
        sheet3.Cells(R, 6).Interior.ColorIndex = 40
        sheet3.Cells(R, 7).Interior.ColorIndex = 40
        sheet3.Cells(R, 8).Interior.ColorIndex = 40
        sheet3.Cells(R, 9).Interior.ColorIndex = 40
        sheet3.Cells(R, 10).Interior.ColorIndex = 40
        sheet3.Cells(R, 11).Interior.ColorIndex = 40
        sheet3.Cells(R, 12).Interior.ColorIndex = 40
        sheet3.Cells(R, 13).Interior.ColorIndex = 40
        sheet3.Cells(R, 14).Interior.ColorIndex = 40
        sheet3.Cells(R, 15).Interior.ColorIndex = 40
        sheet3.Cells(R, 16).Interior.ColorIndex = 40
        sheet3.Cells(R, 17).Interior.ColorIndex = 40
        sheet3.Cells(R, 18).Interior.ColorIndex = 40
        sheet3.Cells(R, 19).Interior.ColorIndex = 40
        sheet3.Cells(R, 20).Interior.ColorIndex = 40
        sheet3.Cells(R, 21).Interior.ColorIndex = 40
        sheet3.Cells(R, 22).Interior.ColorIndex = 40
        sheet3.Cells(R, 23).Interior.ColorIndex = 40
        sheet3.Cells(R, 24).Interior.ColorIndex = 40
        sheet3.Cells(R, 25).Interior.ColorIndex = 40
        sheet3.Cells(R, 26).Interior.ColorIndex = 40
        sheet3.Cells(R, 27).Interior.ColorIndex = 40
        sheet3.Cells(R, 28).Interior.ColorIndex = 40
        sheet3.Cells(R, 29).Interior.ColorIndex = 40
        sheet3.Cells(R, 30).Interior.ColorIndex = 40
        sheet3.Cells(R, 31).Interior.ColorIndex = 40
        sheet3.Cells(R, 32).Interior.ColorIndex = 40
        sheet3.Cells(R, 33).Interior.ColorIndex = 40
        sheet3.Cells(R, 34).Interior.ColorIndex = 40
        sheet3.Cells(R, 35).Interior.ColorIndex = 40
     End If
Next cl
On Error GoTo 0

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
```

'----------------------------------------

```
ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False
Dim NextRow As Range
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Set NextRow = Range("A" & Sheets("Sheet3").UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1)
sheet1.Range("A2:AI50").Copy
sheet3.Activate
NextRow.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Set NextRow = Nothing

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
```

'-------------------------------------------

```
ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False
Dim ListCount As Integer
Dim XCtr      As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

ListCount = Sheets("Sheet3").Range("F2:AI50").Rows.Count
Sheets("Sheet3").Range("F2").Select

Do Until ActiveCell = ""
For XCtr = 1 To ListCount

If ActiveCell.Row <> Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(XCtr, 6).Row Then
If ActiveCell.Value = Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(XCtr, 6).Value Then
Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(XCtr, 1).Delete xlUp
Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(XCtr, 2).Delete xlUp
Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(XCtr, 3).Delete xlUp
Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(XCtr, 4).Delete xlUp
Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(XCtr, 5).Delete xlUp
Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(XCtr, 6).Delete xlUp
Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(XCtr, 7).Delete xlUp
Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(XCtr, 8).Delete xlUp
Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(XCtr, 9).Delete xlUp
Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(XCtr, 10).Delete xlUp
Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(XCtr, 11).Delete xlUp
Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(XCtr, 12).Delete xlUp
Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(XCtr, 13).Delete xlUp
Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(XCtr, 14).Delete xlUp
Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(XCtr, 15).Delete xlUp
Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(XCtr, 16).Delete xlUp
Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(XCtr, 17).Delete xlUp
Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(XCtr, 18).Delete xlUp
Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(XCtr, 19).Delete xlUp
Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(XCtr, 20).Delete xlUp
Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(XCtr, 21).Delete xlUp
Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(XCtr, 22).Delete xlUp
Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(XCtr, 23).Delete xlUp
Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(XCtr, 24).Delete xlUp
Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(XCtr, 25).Delete xlUp
Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(XCtr, 26).Delete xlUp
Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(XCtr, 27).Delete xlUp
Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(XCtr, 28).Delete xlUp
Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(XCtr, 29).Delete xlUp
Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(XCtr, 30).Delete xlUp
Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(XCtr, 31).Delete xlUp
Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(XCtr, 32).Delete xlUp
Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(XCtr, 33).Delete xlUp
Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(XCtr, 34).Delete xlUp
Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(XCtr, 35).Delete xlUp
XCtr = XCtr + 1
End If
End If

Next XCtr
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

MsgBox ("Updated!")
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Instead of applying color and deleting to each cell one by one 
Why don't you color the range of cells at a time. Which boosts your code performance.

```
sheet3.Range(Cells(R, 1),Cells(R,35).Interior.ColorIndex = 40
```

For deleting also same as well.

```
sheet3.Range(Cells(XCtr, 1),Cells(XCtr, 35)).Delete xlUp
```